# Difficulty in making Python dictionary (xpath/CSS selector)

Tags: css, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I have a below code and would like to make a dictionary as {"100":"ABC"} and {"200":"DEF"}

```
<ul class="net">
    <li id="100">
        <a>ABC</a>
    </li>
    <li id="200">
        <a>DEF</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried with below code but I don't know how to pass a variable in xpath attribute.

```
list_of_id = response.css('ul.net>li::attr(id)').extract()
for i in list_of_id:
    j = dict()
    j[i] = response.xpath('//ul/li[@id="i"]/a/text()').extract()
```

Please help.

Comment: *dictionary as {"100":"ABC"} and {"200":"DEF"}...* Do you want to make separate dictionaries for each `<li>` or single dictionary `{"100":"ABC", "200":"DEF"}` ? Note that declaring `j` inside `for` loop means that you'll get dictionary only for the last `i` in `list_of_id`

Comment: @Andersson: I want to make separate dictionary for each i. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selectors to serve the purpose. Give it a shot:

```
html='''
<ul class="net">
    <li id="100">
        <a>ABC</a>
    </li>
    <li id="200">
        <a>DEF</a>
    </li>
</ul>
'''

from lxml.html import fromstring
tree = fromstring(html)
for item in tree.cssselect(".net li"):
    num = item.attrib['id']
    name = item.cssselect("a")[0].text
    item={num:name} 
    print(item)
```

Results:

```
{'100': 'ABC'}
{'200': 'DEF'}
```

Comment: Thanks! I want to add a symbol after every character except space. I tried with below but couldn't succeed. Please help
name = "ABC XYZ"
x=raw_input("Enter the symbol")
print '{0}'.format(x).join(a for a in name if a!=0)

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
j[i] = response.xpath('//ul/li[@id="i"]/a/text()').extract()
```

to this:

```
j[i] = response.xpath("//ul/li[@id="+i+"]/a/text()").extract()
```